# Multiple keyboard shortcuts for one command in xfce4

Tags: xfce

I am trying to add two keyboard shortcuts for switching to right workspace in xubuntu with xfce4.12:

- ctrl+alt+right
- ctrl+alt+page_up

In **window manager -> keyboard**, there you can only specify one key-combination. When adding another entry in **settings editor -> xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts**, only the last one counts. Same in the **xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml** file.

Would there still be a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In the forums there was an answer many years back on how to do this. It no longer works. I have asked on the forums if there is another way, but as of right now my answer is "no, you can't get two keyboard shortcuts".

https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=11038

However, as a workaround you may be able to add a shortcut under:

Keyboard->Application Shortcuts->Command

To create a custom command (a bash script maybe?) that maps to a specific keyboard shortcut, and then somehow implement a bash function to achieve the behavior you desire. I haven't attempted this yet or I'd say that's a good solution.